# Запуск файла из ресурсов

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите можно ли бинарный файл (.exe ) запухнуть в ресурсы?

И запустить его из ресурсов не распаковывая в отдельную папку?

Comment: Можно. Придется только свой загрузчик написать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, А есть примеры как запустить файл из ресурсов?

Comment: Есть, в троянах. Запуск осуществляется не из ресурсов напрямую, а из выделенной памяти.